# PixelCompare extensions: compareTwoModels is not a function

Tags: autodesk-forge

I follow the instructions from:

```
// Load 2 sheets
viewer.loadModel('scissors1.pdf', {}, (model1) => {
  viewer.loadModel('scissors2.pdf', {}, async (model2) => {
    // Compare them 
    const pcExt = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare');
    pcExt.compareTwoModels(model1, model2);
  });
});
```

and get the error: pcExt.compareTwoModels is not a function

It's meaning this function does not exist in extensions.
Someone can help me How to compare 2 directly pdf files

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PixelExtension` class *does* include a method called `compareTwoModels`. Try going to this [live demo](https://aps-simple-viewer-nodejs.autodesk.io/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0), open the browser console, and type

```js
pixelCompareExt = await NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.PixelCompare')
pixelCompareExt.compareTwoModels
```

If you're using an older version of the viewer, it's possible that this method was not available then. In that case, please consider migrating to version 7.*